# Centering CSS grid divs with iFrame and Img

Tags: html, css, iframe

So I want to create a grid on my site that has 2 i frames at the top and 2 imgs below e.g

```
X X
X X
```

I have managed to get some code working, but it doesn't look quite right, right now the grid is stuck to the left-hand side of the page and in mobile view it just goes off the screen and doesn't fit to a mobile version, another issue is there is a random gap between each column. E.g below.

```css
iframe {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.plotly-charts {
  justify-content: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="plotly-charts">
  <div class="charts">
    <iframe width="600px" height="500px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="someframe"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="charts">
    <iframe width="600px" height="500px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="someframe"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="charts">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/525eff/ffffff" alt="Word Cloud Positive" style="width:300px; height:300px;">
  </div>
  <div class="charts">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/525eff/ffffff" alt="Word Cloud Negative-Neutral" style="width:300px; height:300px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove width/height attributes from iframe, make it flexible with CSS, also remove inline styles from you images and make it responsive.
Also, make **.charts** flex. In this case you can align this cells' content.

See CSS Code snippet part comments for more details.

Expand Code snippet to fullpage, to see example

```css
.plotly-charts {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  /* add grid gaps (gaps between rows and columns) */
  column-gap: 1rem;
  row-gap: 1rem;
}

/* make cell flex */
.charts {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.charts iframe {
  width: 100%;
  /* you can add ratios to your iframe in other way */
  aspect-ratio: 6/5;
}

/* add styles to you images, make it responsive */
.charts img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

/* added for example purposes */
.charts iframe, .charts img {
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="plotly-charts">
  <div class="charts">
    <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="//plotly.com/~mathewsjoyy/3.embed?logo=false&link=false&autosize=true"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="charts">
    <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="//plotly.com/~mathewsjoyy/1.embed?logo=false&link=false&autosize=true"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="charts">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Word Cloud Positive">
  </div>
  <div class="charts">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Word Cloud Negative-Neutral">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Bootstrap.. Or you should use media queries including some Javascript... Bootstrap is easy tho

```html
<!--Import bootstrap-->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!--Add classes to your elements-->
<!--No need of grids instead use div classes-->

<div class="text-center d-flex col-md-4">
<h1>hello world</h1>
</div>

<!--Bootstrap script-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

that's it

Comment: There is no reason to add full library to adjust one block.